# MySQL stop responsing when modify main tables

Tags: mysql, cache, update, query, optimization

It's an InnoDB database. The query cache has 1.2GB in size with 300k queries in the cache. Most of the cached queries are related to 3 major tables (260MB data length plus 600MB index length altogether). Everytime I tried to insert new entry or update existing entries in these 3 tables, MySQL slowed down a lot just like the server is dead. I got "Timeout" if I open my website in browser.

I check the Munin stats, it shows 95% of the query cache are cleared after the operation so I guess the sudden overload was caused by inserting entries to heavy-read tables. And during the overload, Munin just shows a white strip on the graph so you may get an idea on how bad the situation was.

How can I optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

Download mysqltuner.pl and run it against your database server:

http://blog.mysqltuner.com/download/

Something sounds horribly mis-optimized.

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are all in InnoDB format, you should first tune the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` setting. Usually I tune this value to be about 80% of my system memory. Also, check the value of `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`. If it's set to the default of `1`, it will flush at every transaction commit which can cause a lot of disk I/O (which appears to be what you're suffering from). If you don't require your database to be 100% ACID compliant, you should set this value to `0` or `2`. Here's the relevant snippet from MySQL pages:

> If the value of
>   innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  is 0,
>   the log buffer is written out to the
>   log file once per second and the flush
>   to disk operation is performed on the
>   log file, but nothing is done at a
>   transaction commit. When the value is
>   1, the log buffer is written out to
>   the log file at each transaction
>   commit and the flush to disk operation
>   is performed on the log file. When the
>   value is 2, the log buffer is written
>   out to the file at each commit, but
>   the flush to disk operation is not
>   performed on it. However, the flushing
>   on the log file takes place once per
>   second also when the value is 2. Note
>   that the once-per-second flushing is
>   not 100% guaranteed to happen every
>   second, due to process scheduling
>   issues.

I usually set this to `2`. Good luck!

Comment: current innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to 3GB, and innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit is already set to 2.